# Finding density functions for modified variables

Tags: statistics

I'm currently struggling with a question pertaining to density functions:

> Let X be an Exponential random variable with mean 1. Find the density
>   function for $Y = {\sqrt X} $. Evaluate the density function (to 2
>   decimal points) of Y at the value 1.5.

What I've done so far is taken the square root the probability density function of X, $e^{-x}$, and replaced the variable *x* with *y*,  $\sqrt{1-e^{-y}}$. The CDF would then be $F(y) = \sqrt{1-e^{-y}}$. At $y = 1.5$, this evaluates to 0.88 (to 2 decimal points) but this is incorrect, and the whole procedure just feels wrong.

Any ideas on how to approach this?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try beginning by working with the CDF, that is,

$$F_Y(y) = P(Y\leq y) = P(\sqrt{X} \leq y) = P(X \leq y^2) = F_X(y^2).$$

Therefore, the density of $Y$ can be found by differentiating, i.e.,

$$f_Y(y) = \frac{d}{dy}F_Y(y) = \frac{d}{dy}F_X(y^2) = \frac{d}{dy}\left(1-e^{-y^2}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Use the cumulative. $$\sqrt X \le y$$ is equivalent to $$X \le y^2$$.